# ¿Cómo conectar a la clase de una API en Android (Java)?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, api, android-volley

¡Buenas tardes!

Estoy haciendo una aplicación que se conecta a una API (en php) que he programado también. La API debería estar en el servidor (API Rest).Para conectarme he visto que hay que usar volley pero mi pregunta está en, si la api tiene clases, ¿Cómo llamo a las funciones de esa clase?

Un ejemplo de clase en mi API es:

```
class User
{
    private $connection;

    function __construct($connection)
    {
        $this->connection = $connection;
    }

    /**
     * This function verify that the user wrote the same password that he has in the Data Base
     * @param user email of the user
     * @param password password of the user
     * @return is_same if the password is the same as the password that is in the data base, it returns true
     * if not, or there is another problem it returns false
     */
    function verify(String $user, String $password)
    {
        $is_same = false;
        $email = filter_var($user, FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL);

        if (filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
            //more security
            $res = $this->connection->prepare("SELECT contraseña FROM usuario WHERE correo = ? ");
            if($res != false){
                $res->bind_param('s',$user);
                $res->execute();
                $results = $res->get_result();
                if ($results && $results->num_rows > 0) {
                    //There is just one
                    if($a_res =  mysqli_fetch_assoc($results)){
                        $is_same = password_verify($password, $a_res['contraseña']);
                    }
                }

            }
            $res->close();

        }

        echo json_encode(array("USER_VERIFY"=>$is_same));
    }

}
```

¿Cómo podría llamar a Verify desde Android (estou usando Java) si está dentro de la clase User?

Por ahora lo que he encontrado es que llame con Volley pero no encontré un ejemplo donde lo hiciera por clases, también vi que podía hacer librerías dentro de Android pero claro eso no sería entonces la API Rest del servidor.
¡Muchas gracias de antemano!

Comment: No puedes llamar directamente a una función que está en el servidor desde un cliente (no importa si es Android, web, o lo que sea). Tienes que definir un endpoint en PHP (algo así como /user/{userId}/verifiy, que a su vez llame a la función verify y le pase los parámetros.
Puedes usar Volley para eso, pero también puedes crear unas clases en Android que serían el cliente de tu REST API (internamente también podrían usar Volley), aunque esto sería aconsejable si planeas acceder a tu REST API desde varios clientes distintos que podrían reutilizar estas clases cliente.

Comment: Así que debería tener varias clases que accedan a los endpoint en la aplicación. Pero entonces, por ejemplo, en la aplicación para acceder a la función verify, ¿Debería de en android llamar al endpoint, ese endpoint será una función en php que tendrá un objeto de la clase User y a su vez llamará a la función verify?
Además la función de php que llama a la de verify , no debería d estar en una clase, ¿Verdad?